# How to add a mobile optimised external CSS to a Shopify site

Tags: css, shopify

I want to add an external CSS doc for my mobile optimisation but am unsure how to do this.

I understand that to add a file to the Shopify theme index you must do something like:

```
{{ 'style.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

in the header. But I am unsure of how to wrap this in a `@media` statement, eg:

```
  @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {
  {{ 'mobile.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  }
```

Adding the above just prints `@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {}`

Does anyone know the correct way of using @media with Shopify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Update]** This is a much better way, omitting the `sytlesheet_tag` function completely:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71)' href='{{ 'mobile.css' | asset_url }}' />
```

**Old:**

Include the asset normally:

```
{{ 'mobile.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

And then make sure you put your media query *inside* you `mobile.css` file.